# How to separate objects in a hidden input?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a hidden input that contains some objects in it. I put string "#" between any two objects, but I  want to put a string that isn't on keyboard. How can I do it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    txtRows.Value += MyTable.Rows[i]["Row"].ToString();

    if (i < MyTable.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        txtRows.Value += "#";

    }
}
```

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any character you like in between two strings. For example to use the [ASCII record separator character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_separator#Field_separators), use this:

```
if (i < MyTable.Rows.Count - 1)
{
    txtRows.Value += '\x1e';

}
```

And then split the value back into multiple strings using the `Split` method:

```
string[] values = txtRows.Split('\x1e');
```

However, I'd recommend using an array or list of inputs instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    txtRows[i].Value = MyTable.Rows[i]["Row"].ToString();
}
```

Of course, you'll probably have to modify how you add these hidden elements to your form, but it's a much nicer way of handling these sorts of problems.